# Invalid Syntax on community.mysql.mysql_user with Ansible AWX

Tags: linux, ansible, mariadb, ansible-awx

I am trying to run a playbook through AWX where I want to create a mariadb user with permissions. The playbook works nicely when run from ansible on my local machine. However, when I try to run the job on AWX, I get the following error :

> "module_stdout": "Traceback (most recent call last):\r\n  File "/home/ansible/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1685691063.0199862-220-69171919718447/AnsiballZ_mysql_user.py", line 107, in \r\n    _ansiballz_main()\r\n  File "/home/ansible/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1685691063.0199862-220-69171919718447/AnsiballZ_mysql_user.py", line 99, in _ansiballz_main\r\n    invoke_module(zipped_mod, temp_path, ANSIBALLZ_PARAMS)\r\n  File "/home/ansible/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1685691063.0199862-220-69171919718447/AnsiballZ_mysql_user.py", line 48, in invoke_module\r\n    run_name='**main**', alter_sys=True)\r\n  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/runpy.py", line 205, in run_module\r\n    return _run_module_code(code, init_globals, run_name, mod_spec)\r\n  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/runpy.py", line 96, in _run_module_code\r\n    mod_name, mod_spec, pkg_name, script_name)\r\n  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code\r\n    exec(code, run_globals)\r\n  File "/tmp/ansible_community.mysql.mysql_user_payload_r3e02o87/ansible_community.mysql.mysql_user_payload.zip/ansible_collections/community/mysql/plugins/modules/mysql_user.py", line 352, in \r\n  File "", line 969, in _find_and_load\r\n  File "", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked\r\n  File "", line 664, in _load_unlocked\r\n  File "", line 634, in _load_backward_compatible\r\n  File "/tmp/ansible_community.mysql.mysql_user_payload_r3e02o87/ansible_community.mysql.mysql_user_payload.zip/ansible_collections/community/mysql/plugins/module_utils/mysql.py", line 22, in \r\n  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pymysql/**init**.py", line 59, in \r\n    from . import connections  # noqa: E402\r\n  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 206\r\n    ):\r\n    ^\r\nSyntaxError: invalid syntax\r\n"

Here's the task for creating the user :

```yaml
- name : Create mariadb user
  community.mysql.mysql_user:
    login_user: root
    login_password: "{{ root_password }}"
    name: user
    password: "{{ mariadb_user_pw }}"
    priv: "*.*:PROCESS,SELECT,CREATE,CREATE TABLESPACE,INSERT"
    state: present
```

Comment: Please make sure the [requirements](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/mysql/mysql_user_module.html#requirements) are met and up-to-date on the target host.

Comment: Requirements are met when I run the playbook from an ansible machine so I guess it is the same for AWX

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ensure the hosts have the correct package installed.
Include this in your playbook:

```yaml
- name: ensure mysql package for the mysql api is installed
  pip:
    name: pymysql
    executable: pip3
```

--

you should check your awx container.
either by logging in to the container itself, and check stuff manually, or you can do this w ansible as well.

```yaml
- shell: locate ansible-galaxy
  delegate_to: localhost
  register: check_galaxy

- debug:
    msg: "{{ check_galaxy.stdout }}"
  delegate_to: localhost
```

Then, once you have the output, simply check the installed roles and it versions

```yaml
- shell: ansible-galaxy collection list
  delegate_to: localhost
  register: check_collection

- debug:
    msg: "{{ check_collection }}"
  delegate_to: localhost
```

Comment: Tried adding those lines to the playbook but it did not work. Once again, it does work when the playbook is run from an ansible machine so I don't think the packages on the host is the problem. Maybe on the container AWX starts to run the playbook ?

Comment: Well then check the version of ansible and of the community.mysql collection on the machine where it works and compare it to the ones running inside awx. And if needed align.

Comment: Then indeed it sounds like there are issues on the controller/container in AWX.
See my updated answers for 'how to debug' this.

Comment: I managed to make it work by using an older version of PyMysql